# How do I add OpenLayers “overlays” using Vue.js

Tags: openlayers, overlay, vue.js

I can't figure out how to implement an OpenLayers "overlay" in my Vue.js app. There doesn't seem to be much guidance online about how to do this. The Vue component below gives me the map with the vectorlayer, but the overlay does not appear.

PS: Also, if you think there are easier ways of implementing OpenLayers into a Vue framework recommendations are highly welcome. This approach doesn't feel like it's the best.

```
<template>
  <div ref="map-root" class="map-container">
    <div ref="marker" class="marker-container"></div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import View from 'ol/View'
  import Map from 'ol/Map'
  

  import 'ol/ol.css'

 
  import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector'
  import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector'
  import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON'
  import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay'




import {Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';

import hexMap from '../assets/hexMap.geojson'


var styles = [

new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#213e5e',
      width: 1,
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: '#2d93db',
    }),
  }),

]



export default {
    name: 'MapContainer',
    components: {},
    props: {},
    

   
    mounted() {
    
      const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        style: styles,
        source: new VectorSource({
          features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(hexMap),
        }),
      })
      
      new Map({
        target: this.$refs['map-root'],
        layers: [

          vectorLayer
        ],

        overlays: [
          new Overlay({
            position: [ -12201195.312673341482878, 13178920.0129499360919 ],
            element: this.$refs['marker'], 
            stopEvent: false,
          })


        ],

        view: new View({
          zoom: 1,
          center: [0, 0],
          constrainResolution: true,
          minZoom: 2,
          maxZoom:3
        }),
      })
    
    },
    
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  

  .map-container {
    background-color: #213e5e;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;

  }

  .marker-container {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(136, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #0FF;
        opacity: 0.5;
      }

</style>
```

Comment: What is the style of marker container div? Does it have any dimensions/content?

Comment: Thanks for the response TomazicM! Embarrassingly, that was the problem indeed. I just had to add some content. Thanks a lot!